# Joomla 3 Website loading without the css

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, cache, k2store

I am using a joomla version 3.+ with k2 and k2store 
Recently we ran into a issue which we are unable to solve 
When we enter the site is showing without any css like a regular HTML Page
here is the screenshot 
I am using a Template called Favourite - 
[image: this is the menu which I am seeing]

[image]

I am unable to understand why is it showing like this without any template 
If am trying to access the clear cache

```
DirectoryIterator::__construct(/home/server/public_html/domain/demo/cache) [<a href='directoryiterator.--construct'>directoryiterator.--construct</a>]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console?

Comment: I didnt but i did just now and there were many errors like `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS  ` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined ` ! how should i tacke these error and I solved the directory error by creating directory in website folder

Comment: Check your template index.php file and see how the assets are being loaded

Comment: Have you installed any CDN extension? Are files loaded from the same site? Do you have any security restriction to deliver CSS files? Any hidden PHP Error?

Comment: I m using k2 with k2 store .I aslo have sh404sef lite version installed

Comment: curious to know what is a CDN Extension ? how does it work ? any examples @Anibal

Comment: To implement a CDN, you can install NoNumber's CDN for Joomla! or Extly's XT Adaptive Images (Disclaimer: I have developed this extension ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache directory was getting deleted frequently so a directory under root folder named "cache" and give it directory permission of 755 and enable the progressive caching for it.took one day but finally got it.